# Tomcat 9 открывает старый проект

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

1 Установил для проекта(проект 1) tomcat 9, поработал с ним и забыл.
2 Когда работаю с другим(проект 2) проектом и запускаю через IntelliJ IDEA, по localhost открывается старый проект с формой логина
2.1 Пробовал удалить его из webapp
2.2 Совсем удалил tomcat. Даже после удаления, при запуске проекта из IDE открывался старый проект на localhost какой бы порт я не использовал
2.3 Искал по всей системе, где он мог остаться во временных файлах через find, не нашел
Результата ничего не дало.

ОС - Ubuntu 16.04
Tomcat - 9.0.31

Где может лежать war файл в системе, что при любом открытии localhost, открывается старый проект?

Comment: выпили все java процессы и перезапусти, либо перезапусти пк

Comment: Попробуй почистить кэш в браузере (открываешь DevTools - F12), правой клавишей по кнопке обновления страницы, выбираешь очистка кэша и жёсткая перезагрузка

Comment: Нет, не помогло очистка кеша и перезагрузка так же не помогла.

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать установить заново tomcat и пересоздать конфигурацию запуска приложения в Ide:

- удаляем старую конфигурацию (или отредактировать) см. приложенный скрин
- создаем новую с указанием пути к новому томкат (поле Application Server)
- указываем war артефакт для деплоя (вкладка Deployment)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

+к комметарию @Санаев, при подобных глюках профилактический перезапуск помогает

Comment: Пробовал, переустанавливать(3 раза), не помогло.
Ваш совет так же не помог =(

Comment: нужно посмотреть в лог файл tomcat-а, можете приложить?
по какой инструкции устанавливаете tomcat ubuntu? прописываете как системный сервис в systemd?

Comment: https://community.vscale.io/hc/ru/community/posts/211836285-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Tomcat-9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Ubuntu-16-04 инструкция
https://yadi.sk/d/DQ3RaAVLH7vENA логи, но я в них не увидел ничего интересного.

Comment: по логам не видно запуска сторонних war файлов. В настройках проекта2 в Idea какие артефакты указаны? Хоткей для просмотра Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S пункт Archifacts

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/QEhb1Kl0Dwbs4w все верно в артифактах, на сколько могу судить.

Comment: попробуйте саму idea перезапусть -> invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Нет, инвалидация кеша и перезагрузка не помогла =(